# django admin custom view in model properties

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I have such models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    ...

class Question(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='question', null=True)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name='question', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    ...

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    text = models.TextField(null=True)
    ...
```

All these models are registered in django admin.
How can I get a custom report table while editing one of a Questions (/admin/qa/question/1/change/):

```
...
editable standart_fields from Question model
...
non-standart report(without editable fields):
all questions:                   related answers to them
User: Question(related to a product) - User: Answer to it
User: Question(if it exists)         - User: answer to it
```

Is it possible in admin site?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom **ModelAdmin** for **Questions** and override the **form** property, as explained at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form.

In your case, you should get the dynamically created form using **ModelAdmin.get_form()** and add the report you want to it, using Django's form framework.